# Why Broadleaf Commerce over Magento or ZenCart?

Tags: java, magento, e-commerce, broadleaf-commerce

I have a site made in java-spring-hibernate we made our self from scratch, it shows a catalog of product and i have the logic for it. I can also manage content and product/categories with it with an administrator we have made in flex. We probably shouldn´t have gone to all the trouble since there are so many cms out there, but what's done it's done. The site renders the content managed in flex in html with jstl.

Thing is now i want to add a ecommerce to it, for that we would have to add all the payment,shipment, orders logic to the administrator and the front end (cart/user). How ever, since there are already things like magento store, i was thinking maybe i should switch and leave my beautiful app to die :/. As i was researching i stumbled upon broadleaf commerce which is an ecommerce back end made in flex-spring-hibernate. It´s relatively new and it supposed to have an active development team. So i guess my question is, Why? if there are so many opensource commerce solutions do they make this kind of effort in developing ? i mean you still have to build the GUI for the users side. Whats their difference with magento, what are the pros ? should i try to integrate with broadleaf ? what are the assests oder then keeping my loved old app ?

Comment: Not sure this is a real question that can be answered, but anyway, keep in mind that the Magento folks have made a stack of money off of their app. Big stacks of money tend to attract competitors.

Answer (score 19):

Let me start off by identifying myself as an employee of Broadleaf Commerce, so I may be somewhat biased. The reason for developing Broadleaf really has everything to do with the platform itself. If you look at the open source e-commerce solutions out there, you are correct in that there are a number of them. However, when you start to filter them by various parameters, including Java, Spring, Hibernate - the list becomes very small. It was always our intent to come up with a compelling e-commerce platform targeted at today's enterprise users. With that theme in mind, we knew we had to go with Java, Spring and Hibernate. This is the core technology stack that is preferred by much of the development community, especially in the enterprise segment. Also, to satisfy the complex domain and integration requirements of these users, we designed the system from the ground up with extensibility in mind. We think of extensibility as a natural extension of the Object Oriented programming techniques you already practice daily. This translates into leveraging the power of Hibernate extension and polymorphism for the domain, as well as the ability to override, tweak or completely replace every service, DAO and entity in the codebase. Our configuration is also extensible, and goes beyond standard Spring application context override to provide more configuration merge capabilities that allow us to pull away some of the additional Broadleaf configuration complexity so you can focus on the configuration that matters for your app. So while the end results may be similar between our software and others, we believe the decision on what path to take to achieve that end goal is an important one and Broadleaf Commerce offers a powerful and flexible way to get there.

I feel I should also briefly mention, since you mention Flex above, that we are currently in development of our 1.5 release, which includes a re-worked administrative application based on GWT that will replace our current Flex-based admin. This choice has allowed us to propagate the same theme of extensibility that we already embrace in the core platform to our administrative platform. The new admin will offer the same flexibility for override and replacement through Object Oriented programming paradigms that developers already enjoy in the core platform. In addition, the admin application automatically recognizes your entity extensions and includes your additional fields in the admin interface without any coding effort on your behalf. The admin interface also honors entity polymorphism and will adjust the editing interface according to each type (think of a media product that has two extensions in the form of book and movie - even though they are both media entities, they each have unique fields and the admin interface honors this distinction). We're also working on changesets and some other interesting features for 1.5. We're targeting milestone releases beginning around April, so stay tuned for more.

Comment: Wow, great answer! thank you! so i guess it leaves me with 2 questions. Where can i get started on pluging broadleaf with my app since it uses the same technology, can some one help me for a fee or something? and second, what do you approach do you recomend for making an admin for payment, shiping, taxes ? it sounds like a 3 month development to me.

Comment: You can get started on our documentation site [link] (http://www.broadleafcommerce.org/confluence/display/core/home). The docs could still use some additional meat, but they are a great reference for getting started. Our forums can also be a helpful place to ask questions and get answers [link] (http://www.broadleafcommerce.org/forum). If you need on-site assistance with architectural design, implementation or integration concerns, then our implementation partner Credera [link] (http://www.credera.com) is a great resource.

Comment: As for the approach for making an admin for payment, shipping and taxes, I would suggest extending the 1.5 admin platform with the pages and functionality you require. The 1.5 admin should be available for you to start using around the April timeframe. We will be including new documentation and examples that will provide guidance on using the 1.5 admin.

Answer (score 2):

What Spring and Hibernate are missing is a proper datamodel and erp application so everybody starts building their own. 
We are all building together on the same application and framework. 
That is just OFBiz: framework and a proper datamodel and application. You know the best part? It is not controlled by a single company but by the biggest open source foundation in the world: The Apache foundation sponsored by all large IT companies.

Anybody starting his own implementation of either erp of ecommerce should really reconsider.

More info on Apache ofbiz?
http://www.ofbiz.info
http://ofbiz.apache.org

Regards,
Hans

Comment: Not crazy about OFBiz or, in fact, any of the existing OSS solutions.  We're using Magento at the moment, but we're currently in the process of building our own e-commerce engine from scratch (Java, Spring, MongoDB, no Hibernate (we're anti-ORM)).  It's nearly done, and the performance compared to Magento is insane (~15 ms. response times compared to 3+ seconds).  The memory footprint is also lower, and the logic is tight and clean and modularized.  This is more of a seal of approval for Java than anything else.  I can't imagine writing a huge piece of software in a scripting language.

Comment: You might want to find a new link for that it is 404: try https://ofbiz.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

There is one **Java Connector for Magento's API** called as [**Magja**](https://github.com/magja).

Note: No support after 2012!